# Migration causing duplicate questions - How to manage this?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, stack-exchange

With the ability to migrate questions, I have found quite a few duplicates on both SU and MSO due to questions being migrated from others sites.

Do we handle these as normal duplicates or should we just let them be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flag them for moderator attention as per usual!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/

Answer (score 0):

I'd say deal with it on a case-by-case basis.

Setting up a rule for that isn't a good idea.