# How to make migration more clear to new users?

Tags: discussion, migration

Migration was discussed often, however I couldn't find another question about it.

A phenomenon which happens often is the "self duplicate", because of "belongs to *****" comment under question. The original poster sees that, checks the other site, and copies his question there. A few minutes after, his original question gets migrated to the site, after enough votes.
So the other site inherits 2 similar questions, for no reason, one is to close for duplicate.

**How can we make the "migration" process more clear to new (and other) users?**

There is nothing in FAQ about it, and it's understandable, because migrating, even if happening often, is something which wouldn't happen most of times if the FAQ was read and respected. Since this FAQ states "ask such questions on another site", no reason to add "but if you do anyway, we will migrate it for you", it would indeed be silly.

**How to educate people who are leaving comment to leave a more complete one, then?** Instead of putting tags, or writing shortly "belongs on S#.", or worse "you should ask this question on S#.", they should simply state that this question doesn't belong there, and will be migrated there, so the original poster should create an account there and wait for it, but shouldn't ask again the question.

The migration system is completely invisible for a new user. His "good behavior" seems to be asking the question on the good place, then. So how can we make it more clear?

**Edit:** [Related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7072/migration-causing-duplicate-questions-how-to-manage-this) (but more about handling these duplicates and not preventing them in the first place).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7072/migration-causing-duplicate-questions-how-to-manage-this

Comment: Not really duplicate... nor spam, but hey, I guess it puts more originality in "vote for close" reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to make it more clear to new users is to fix up how current and older  users leave these dizzying comments.

Needs to be some education on their part to help with the fact that a brand new user might not be familiar with how the sites are interlinked as opposed to traditional forums where they would be distinct other sites.

Comments such as

> This belongs on ... | Should be on ... | Ask your question on ...

only makes the new user think, "Oh, okay, I'll just go and repost it on that other site."

Whereas a better comment would be something like

> Your question is set to move to the proper site. Please follow the link when your question is closed. **Please do not re-post.** Just follow the trail and continue on from there.

Comment: I like this kind of comment, I will probably re-use something like this.

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is add a comment to say that the question will be migrated and that they should head over to Super User or Stack Overflow or Server Fault and create an account and associate it with their existing account so that they'll have ownership of the question when it arrives.

*P.S. Sorry about the vote to close.*

Comment: Hey, don't apologize, find 4 more! :)

Comment: I voted to close because I read most of the question and your comment before reading Gnoupi's explanation - at which point I realised I probably shouldn't have.